# Event white screen of death when user registers for an event

Tags: civievent

I upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.4 on Joomla 3.4.2 after a year on older versions. I've cloned a previously working but expired event. Registration from the back-end works fine but from the front-end gives this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_Payment_Form::setPaymentFieldsByProcessor() in /home/***/www/www/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php on line 388

If I make it an unpaid event (Configure Fees with Paid Event = No), I get a different error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_Payment_Form::buildPaymentForm() in /home/***/www/www/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php on line 114

Advice please!

Comment: Did you clear caches?

Comment: Do you get the same error with a freshly created (non-clone) event?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: I'm seeing the same fatal error in relation to trying to show a contribution page using 4.6.4 on a new Wordpress install.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.  There seems to be a conflict in this version (Civicrm 4.6.4) with the following extensions:

- GoCardless
- Smart Debit
- UK Direct Debit

When I disabled all three, the problem went away.  One of these extensions must be using the same method call.

Comment: setPaymentFieldsByProcessor() and buildPaymentForm() were added to CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php in Civi 4.6. This file is overridden in UK Direct Debit: uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.ukdirectdebit/CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php so if the version of the extension pre-dates 4.6, that explains the errors. I believe Veda are working on a 4.6 version.

Comment: We had the same problem, and there is a 4.6 version available from Veda that solves this problem - contact Rajesh